# Automatically change strong named assembly version in resx?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a .NET 3.0 project which should be installed into GAC. I have some strong named assemblies, and in one of them there is control, which is used on a form of another strong named assembly.

When I change the version number of all assemblies and recompile the project, the resx files still reference the old assembly version until I open the form with the designer.

The whole project is compiled by a build server, which also sets the assembly version, therefore opening the form in a designer is not possible. So is there a chance to do the update programmatically?

The current solution is "search and replace" but sometimes we hit version numbers of 3rd-party assemblies that should not be changed.

Comment: What are you asking?  Want to know if you can write a program to modify an XML file.  Yes.

Comment: I just wanted to know if there is a best practise for updating the resx files of a form that uses controls from strong named assemblies. I could not imagine that it is the intention of microsoft, to update the resx files via "search and replace."

Comment: Obviously there is no best practice, I suppose. The situation gets even worse, when the designer complains about a missing reference (the old assembly) after the update and refuses to fix the reference itself. We ended up suggesting our users to use the `DesignerSerializationVisibility` attribute with `Hidden` for all public properties of our types. I woudn't name this a 'solution' though...